# File upload not working on certain server

Tags: php, upload

I have website which uploads files to api/uploads - it works locally and on my heroku server. But it fails on the production server I have been given.

the site sits in the folder - public/

I have ran the following command:

```
chmod -Rf 777 public/api/uploads
```

and added the following to my htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

Non of this works - is there anything else I can try?

EDIT:

Some debugging gets the following:

uploading a file: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Looking at phpinfo() file_uploads is set to 'On' - how can permission be denied when uploads is on?

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like checking `$_FILES['whatever']['error']` to see **WHY** the upload failed?

Comment: You could try debugging...

Comment: please check the following value in phpinfo(): upload_tmp_dir

Comment: hey its "no value" i'm guessing this is wrong?

Comment: no, in this case it is the systems default folder, see:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: normally this is the /tmp/ folder. Ensure that the apache user has write permissions for this folder

Comment: Hey - turns out I didn't have the permission level to change any of this - I had the server admin change the permission to the specific folder. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

By my experience, you might want to check the ownership of the folder you used to store the uploaded data. You can use `chown` command to change the ownership of the folders and files in Linux

Comment: As he used chmod 777 the ownership does not matter

Answer (score 0):

**Have you created the folder that the uploaded files are stored in?**

**Are the Linux owner and group set properly on the folder and files?**

You can change the owner and group using this command;

```
sudo chown -R <YOUR WEBSERVER USERNAME>:<YOUR WEBSERVER GROUP> <PATH TO FOLDER>
```

**Do you have Open_Basedir enabled?#**

See: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: Hey I tried this command a while ago - also getting permission denied

Comment: Did you check the Open_Basedir value in php.ini?